Jenkins checks out svn repository adding folder '.svn' into each subfolder
We have recently installed new version of Jenkins, going from 1.638 to more recent 2.346.1. We didn't update, but went for a completely fresh installation.
We use Subversion Plug-in 2.15.5
It checks out code without any issues so far. What we though noticed when unit tests started suddenly failing, is that when code is checked out, folder .svn is added into each subfolder in code folder.
This breaks some of our tests. How do we make Jenkins or this plugin check out code with a single .svn folder in root folder?
Thanks a lot

Svn added .svn dirs into all subdirs prior to version 1.7. This changed in version 1.7. So it seems that you are using some ancient version of the svn client.

Subervion plugin for Jenkins 2.15.5 is about 2.5 years old, even the plugin in the older Jenkins version didn't do it, though I do not remember which version it was...
